# Separate out comma separated items in a data frame column and get individual counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column which has multiple comma separated values:

| A |
| --- |
| a, b, c, d |
| a, c |
| b, d |
| b, d |
| c, d |

I want the counts of each of these comma separated values in the column as a data frame like so:

| A | Count |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 4 |

Is there a straight forward way in pandas to achieve this?

I have currently parsed column A to get the list of unique items in A. And then created a dictionary again by parsing the column again and checking if item exists in the individual cell.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this (i) split the string into an iterable, (ii) explode the iterables into separate rows, (iii) count the values:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'a, b, c, d', 1: 'a, c', 2: 'b, d', 3: 'b, d', 4: 'c, d'}})

df['A'].str.split(', ').explode().value_counts()

d    4
c    3
b    3
a    2
```

Answer (score 1):

With `get_dummies` and `sum`:

```
df['A'].str.get_dummies(", ").sum().reset_index(name='Count')
```

---

```
  index  Count
0     a      2
1     b      3
2     c      3
3     d      4
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the column on `,` , then `explode`, call `value_counts` to get the counts, sort the index, call `to_frame` to create datarame out of it, finally reset the index:

```py
result = (df['A']
            .str
            .split(', ')
            .explode()
            .value_counts()
            .sort_index()
            .to_frame('Count')
            .reset_index()
        )
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
  index  Count
0     a      2
1     b      3
2     c      3
3     d      4
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
pd.DataFrame({'Count': Counter(', '.join(df['A']).split(', '))}).rename_axis('A')
```

output:

```
   Count
A       
a      2
b      3
c      3
d      4
```

quick benchmark of all proposed answers:

```
                example_df       1000×example
mozway    1.46 ms ± 142 µs      3 ms ± 226 µs
Andreas   2.15 ms ± 156 µs  12.7 ms ± 1.07 ms
ThePyGuy  4.49 ms ± 332 µs  16.8 ms ± 3.27 ms
anky      7.16 ms ± 535 µs    41 ms ± 4.45 ms
```